# Get all posts with only the author's name

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have set a eloquent relationship between my User and Post models and in the migrations, the only thing that points to the Post author is his ID.
I'm building a VueJS Spa frontend and I was wondering how can I get all posts including but only limited to the authors ID and Name+Lastname.

I've heard of DB query builder, but I'd like to strafe away from it.

Currently, I'm grabbing everything with `$posts = Post::all();` and this is the response:

```
    {
      "id": 3,
      "author": 1,
      "subject": "Post subject",
      "content": "The post content!!!!",
      "created_at": "2020-05-31T02:08:53.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-05-31T02:08:53.000000Z"
    }
```

As you can see, there is the "author" field which points to the User ID. I don't want to grab the whole user information due to security reasons and unnecessity.

Post model relation:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User')->select(array('id','name'));
}
```

User model relation:

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

I've also tried:
`Post::with('user:id,name,lastName')->get()`
but the user returns null.

Comment: Since the foreign key is `author` and not `user_id` as eloquent expects, you should pass the custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo method. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @porloscerrosΨ said you should specify second argument which is foreign key and also I believe you should select `author` in your query too.

Your relation

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author');
}
```

The query

```php
Post::with('user:id,author,name,lastName')->get()
```

Comment: Thank you both! This worked. I was completely lost for a couple of hours and thought that Laravel would use the foreign key from the migrations. Didn't know they were 2 separate things. And also it is needed to add the primary table ID - in my case the users.id. Author isn't needed as it's the posts table column and is already there.